# How can a website rank high in SERPs without a blog?

Tags: seo, blog, search-results

So I'm starting a medical practice, and creating a website for it. We don't want to do a blog, as we see no need to duplicate information out there, and we can't resource ongoing. Yet if we don't have regularly updated content, I'm concerned that we'll slide down the SERPs.

How can we rank high without fresh new content? I'm thinking of the following:

- solid linking strategy
- regular social media posts
- ensure relevant content on website (and updated regularly), but no blog.

Your thoughts? Should we just do a blog regardless? I don't want to lose ground for our SERPs, or shoot myself in the foot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blog helps you to build authority on your website. A blog is not a must to have a better ranking.

Considering the website will be about medical practice, i would say if you do not want to do blog then you may like to consider following:

- Have well optimised Google Local Listing.
- Linking Strategy: Do not over do it, think about ways where people can naturally link.
- Social media is a good option.
- Recommend people to review on Google Business Listing.
- Worth considering to put testimonials on the website.

You can get started with blog later if you may want, but with regards to solid linking strategy, think more about getting natural links. Learn more about link schemes.
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66356?hl=en